# Clozure CL on Android

Tags: android, lisp, ccl

CCL is now working on my Android and I have some questions.

1. I transferred Android-headers to the device and tried to run rebuild-ccl:
   Error: File #P"ccl:lib;systems.lisp.newest" not found.
   Sources needed?
2. I ran the following code.
   (do-external-symbols (s (find-package "ARM-ANDROID")) (print s))

And the output list is empty. Situation will change after a rebuilding CCL?

1. Is it possible to using android's graphic and other (java)libraries
   with ccl now?
2. In that compiles aarmc as a result?

Comment: Please check your spelling and rethink your sentences since this is kind of messed up.

Comment: I propose to use the CCL mailing list for such a specific question. All the experts are there.

Comment: I formatted message and sent to mailing-list. My knowledge of English is not great, I'm sorry.